# How to add custom reactions that actually work?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I have been working on this function which gives users roles according to what emoji they chose. If they chose one emoji, they'd get the role that the emoji indicates and so on. I have made the bot react to it's own message, I've set up all of the embeds and I've also set up all of the constants but it just does not seem to work!

Here's my code:

```js
 client.on('message', async Agreemessage => {
     
     
     
      const BoomerEmoji = Agreemessage.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "boomer")
      const RatEmoji = Agreemessage.guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "robincutmoment")
      const BoomerRole = Agreemessage.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Les boomers normaux")
      const RatRole = Agreemessage.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "The normal Rat Haven dwellers")
      const ApprovalEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('RED')
    .setTitle('Hi there new user!')
    .setDescription('Please use either one of the comamnds in order to get a role.')
    .addFields(
      { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B'},
      { name: 'Essential server roles', value: 'The command "^giveBoomerRole" gives you the "Les boomers normaux" role, and the command "^giveRatRole" gives you the "The normal Rat Haven dwellers" role.'},
       { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B'},
      { name: 'Please read this.', value: 'Using the command "^giveBoomerRole" will give you access to only the Boomer Haven compartment, and the comamand "^giveRatRole" will give you access to the Rat Haven compartment. '},
      { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B'},
      {name: 'Read this as well.', value: 'To get access to both of these compartments, please consider using the command "^AccessToBoth" to receive the "Access to both compartments" role.'},
      { name: '\u200b', value: '\u200b'},
      { name: "Have some patience. A moderator will be with you in a bit!", value: "After you have used the command '-agree', please use either one of the commands, depending on which compartment you want to enter. A moderator will approve you shortly."}
      )
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter('Time to pick a role!');
      
      const AgreeErrorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RED')
      .setTitle(`Hello there ${Agreemessage.author.username}!`)
      .setThumbnail('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hAsZCTL__lo/maxresdefault.jpg')
      .setDescription("It seems that you have already been verified!")
      
      const BoomerRoleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setColor("RED")
       .setTitle(`Hi ${Agreemessage.author.username}`)
       .setDescription("It seems that you already have the Boomer Haven role!")
       .setThumbnail("https://wompampsupport.azureedge.net/fetchimage?siteId=7575&v=2&jpgQuality=100&width=700&url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.kym-cdn.com%2Fentries%2Ficons%2Ffacebook%2F000%2F032%2F558%2Ftemp6.jpg")
        const BoomerEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('GREEN')
  .setTitle('Congratulations!')
  .setDescription("You're all set!")
  .setThumbnail('https://i.redd.it/db494tdiwv121.jpg')
  .addFields(
    {name: '\u200b', value: '\u200B'},
    {name: 'Disclaimer:', value: "You now have access to the Boomer Haven compartment of the server. Please wait for a moderator to approve you, and you can then enjoy in the Boomer Rat Haven!"},
  )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Enjoy pls ')
    const RatEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('GREEN')
  .setTitle('Congratulations!')
  .setDescription("You're all set!")
  .setThumbnail('https://i.redd.it/db494tdiwv121.jpg')
  .addFields(
    {name: '\u200b', value: '\u200B'},
    {name: 'Disclaimer:', value: "You now have access to the Rat Haven compartment of the server. Please wait for a moderator to approve you, and you can then enjoy in the Boomer Rat Haven!"},
  )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Enjoy pls ')
      
       if (Agreemessage.content === "-agree") {
         const AgreeMessage = await Agreemessage.channel.send(ApprovalEmbed) 
         if (Agreemessage.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === "Awaiting Verification")) {
         } else return Agreemessage.channel.send(AgreeErrorEmbed)         
          AgreeMessage.react(BoomerEmoji) | AgreeMessage.react(RatEmoji)
    
    
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return [(BoomerEmoji), (RatEmoji)].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === Agreemessage.author.id;
    }; 
    
    AgreeMessage.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();
    
        if (reaction.emoji.name === (BoomerEmoji)) { 
            if (Agreemessage.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === "Les boomers normaux")) return Agreemessage.channel.send(BoomerRoleEmbed).then(console.log(`${Agreemessage.author.username} tried to get the Boomer role, but it turns out that he/she already has it!`))
            else (AgreeMessage.member.roles.add(BoomerRole)).then(Agreemessage.channel.send(BoomerEmbed))
            console.log(`${Agreemessage.author.username} has been given the Boomer role by me.`)
    
     
        } else if (reaction.emoji.name === (RatEmoji)) {
          if (Agreemessage.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === "The normal Rat Haven dwellers")) return Agreemessage.channel.send(RatRoleEmbed).then(console.log(`${Agreemessage.author.username} tried to get the Rat role but it turns out that already have it!`))
          else (AgreeMessage.member.roles.add(RatRole)).then(Agreemessage.channel.send(RatEmbed))
          console.log(`${Agreemessage.author.username} has been given the Rat role by me.`)
        }
       


    });
        
    
    
    
         
         console.log(`${Agreemessage.author.username} is currently seeking approval.`)
         
         
         
         
        } 
       
    
    });
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not enough to diagnose an issue. What goes wrong? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Well, the error does not show at all. I feel like all of the code after const filter’s gone wrong. I think the bot cannot recognize the custom guild emojis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing a full `GuildEmoji` object to an emoji name. You should be using the `name` property.

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) =>  
 [BoomerEmoji.name, RatEmoji.name].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === Agreemessage.author.id;
    
// ...

if (reaction.emoji.name === BoomerEmoji.name) {...)
else if (reaction.emoji.name === RatEmoji.name) {...}
```